# How to display ListItem in Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to create Fragment with ListView, so, I have a ListView with listitem in my Fragment activity, but my listitem is not displayed when i open my fragment, i need help with it, how display items in fragment? When i make this ListView in Activity, all is working well, how fix this? My code here:

**FollowFragment.java**

```
public class FollowFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().setTitle("Подписки");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_follow,container,false);
    }
}
```

**follow_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_follow"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**item_follow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/favourite_match_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/team_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="FC Chelsea"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/team_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Manchester City"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/team_1"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/match_date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:text="25 сентября 2021 года"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/team_2"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_love"
            android:background="#00000000"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/team_2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well that's because you didn't assign an adapter with the correct data to it yet.

- your adapter should extend **ArrayAdapter** and override `getView` in which you should set your view with the correct content based on your data.

what an adapter might look like :

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<YourDataCustomClassHere> {
    ArrayList<YourDataClassHere> data;
    Context context ;
    public MyAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<YourDataCustomClassHere> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.data = objects;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.item_follow, parent, false);
        }
        //example on setting one of your fields 
        ((AppCompatTextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.team_1))
                .setText(data.get(position).getText());
        //set Other Fields here
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

where your data class should be a custom class that holds the correct information for each item in the list and `getText` in `data.get(position).getText()` is an arbitary method I assumed that will be in your custom class to get some sort of text but you're free to replace it with what you want.

- then in your onCreateView you should set the adapter to your ListView like that :

```
public class FollowFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().setTitle("Подписки");
        View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_follow,container,false);
        ListView list = rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        MyAdapter myadapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.item_follow,YourDataArrayListHere);
        list.setAdapter(myadapter);
        return rootView; 
    }
}
```

I trust that you'll find your way and replace **YourDataArrayListHere** with the correct ArrayList of your data custom class.

anyway I hope you reconsider your choice of [ListView](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) as it consume much Ram (Memory) during runtime and use a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) instead